# Ambiguous notation in elementary probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have the random variables $X, Y$ and a joint density $p(x,y)$.
We then have derived densities like $p(x), p(y), p(x|y)$ and $p(y|x)$, which are marginal and conditional densities respectively.

In other areas of mathematics, the symbol $p$ would serve to name a particular, well defined function. Here we are already running into some trouble, since $p$ is only disambiguated when accompanied with symbols $x$, $y$, and $|$. But outside of probability theory, when we have variables $x$ and $y$ such that $x = y = 0.123$, we have sensible expressions like $p(0.123) = p(x = 0.123) = p(y = 0.123)$.

This interpretation does not hold in probability theory, since $p(x = 0.123)$ is pronounced as "the marginal density of $X$, evaluated at $0.123$" and $p(y = 0.123)$ is pronounced as "the marginal density of $Y$, evaluated at $0.123$." and clearly the these values are not equal in general.

So $x$ and $y$ are not variables in the normal sense and there is no way to make sense of an expression like $x = y$.

The situation is even more confused in the expression of entropy as $H[X] = -E[\log p(X)]$. Since $p$ names the joint density, it should take two inputs, not one. Common sense dictates that the unambiguous expression is $H[X] = -E[\log p(x = X)]$. But what about cross entropy between marginals $H[p(x), p(y)]$ which is equal to $-E[\log p(y = X)]$? The term $p(y=X)$ is a complete head scratcher since $p(y = X) \ne p(Y = X)$.

Is there a less ambiguous notation such that the semantics of an expression is clear, but does not impede calculations?

Comment: For example we can see: $f(x,y)$ joint density of $X,Y$. $f_X(x)$ marginal density and so on. Saying: "So $x$
 and $y$
 are not variables in the normal sense and there is no way to make sense of an expression like $x=y$." seems to go way too far.
.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG, having not done probability for a while I somehow forgot about the alternate notation $f_X$. Then we likewise have such densities as $f_{X|Y}$ which seems unambiguous.

Comment: What you call "alternate" notation is what I recall as "standard". I remember seeing $p$, $f$, etc. without subscripts when there is only one random variable under consideration or other circumstances where there is no ambiguity about what function is meant. As soon as things get any more complicated, the subscripts come back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty usual to disambiguate densities $p$ with subscripts, so $p_X(x)$, $p_Y(y)$, $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$ [or sometimes $p_{X|Y}(x,y)$] are commonly written.

For your entropy examples, the entropy of $X$:
$$H(X)=-E[\log(p_X(X))]$$
and the cross-entropy of $Y$ relative to $X$:
$$H(X,Y)=-E[\log(p_Y(X))]$$
seem reasonably unambiguous.

Of course, if you want to talk about the cross-entropy $H(X,Y)$ and the joint entropy $H(X,Y)$ in the same paper, I guess you're stuck.